# OSX and shared memory needing sudo

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory, sudo

I recently found out after updating the OSX software on our server that I am unable to run one of my programs without getting Segmentation Fault 11. It is a simple program which tries to allocate shared memory and then free it. It works fine when i compile and run my file using sudo. Any help would be much appreciated!

Source Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    double *shared;
    int arrsize, shmid;
    arrsize = 10;
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, arrsize * sizeof(double), IPC_CREAT | 666);
    shared = (double*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    shared[2] = 3.0; //source of Segmentation Fault
    shmdt( (void*) shared );
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("Success!");
    return 0;
}
```

System:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.1
BuildVersion:   13B42
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using System V shared memory? OS X mach shared memory is far more powerful if you need features and POSIX shared memory is easier to set up.

Comment: You need to check the return values of all those `shm*` calls.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late response.
Sergey - I was porting a program from ubuntu. I will definitely look at mach shared memory if this program is going to stay on osx.
Andrew - great point! I omitted that portion of the code, but I am definitely doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shmget` call may be failing when running as a normal user because your literal value `666` is being parsed as a decimal literal. You need a leading `0` for it to be recognized as octal as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting your permissions correctly for the shared memory. You have to use the macros in `sys/stat.h` to pass the right permissions. Consult `man 2 chmod`:

```
shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, arrsize * sizeof(double), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergey, I'm not sure if this would fix my issue since I would need to add more macros to allow for another user access to the shared memory. I apologize for not mentioning this in the question.